# Laravel shared hosting, index.php not pointing to root but staying at public_html Laravel 8 Hostinger

Tags: laravel, directory, laravel-8, shared-hosting

I have moved my laravel project to the root directory. and the public folder files to public_html.
when I lunch the URL it want point to the root directory (laravel_market).

it shows

```
Warning: require(/home/u926744684/domains/c2teckmarket.com/public_html/../../laravel_market/vendor/autoload.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/u926744684/domains/c2teckmarket.com/public_html/index.php on line 35

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '/home/u926744684/domains/c2teckmarket.com/public_html/../../laravel_market/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php81/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php81/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /home/u926744684/domains/c2teckmarket.com/public_html/index.php:35 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/u926744684/domains/c2teckmarket.com/public_html/index.php on line 35
```

I tested `php artisan migrate:fresh` it works on the SSH, I think there is no problem with my project, the problem in the index.php not pointing to the root directory.

i have tryded anothor salution changing .htaccess file but nothing

the .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

index.php

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Check If The Application Is Under Maintenance
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If the application is in maintenance / demo mode via the "down" command
| we will load this file so that any pre-rendered content can be shown
| instead of starting the framework, which could cause an exception.
|
*/

if (file_exists($maintenance = __DIR__ . '/../../laravel_market/storage/framework/maintenance.php')) {
    require $maintenance;
}

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| this application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so we don't need to manually load our classes.
|
*/


require __DIR__ . '/../../laravel_market/vendor/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request using
| the application's HTTP kernel. Then, we will send the response back
| to this client's browser, allowing them to enjoy our application.
|
*/


$app = require_once __DIR__ . '/../../laravel_market/bootstrap/app.php';

$kernel = $app->make(Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Request::capture()
)->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Hostinger you have to put the laravel project into the `root/domains/yourdomain.com/{laravel prject}`

[image]